# scala sort indexedseq in place

Tags: sorting, scala

How do you sort an `IndexedSeq` in place in scala? Where's the API function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Currently there is nothing to sort them in-place.

If you really need that it would be possible to convert the `IndexedSeq` to an `Array[AnyRef]` and use `Arrays.sort` from Java (you have to cast to `Array[AnyRef]`, because Scala's arrays are not covariant like Java's).

Interestingly a few weeks ago there was a discussion about adding in-place versions of operation like map, filter and sort to Scala's mutable collections.

I hope after the 2.9 release of parallel collections this could be the next work item on the list to further improve Scala's collection.

It doesn't hurt if people would raise their voice in support of it (or supply a working implememtation) :-).

Comment: There's also in-place sorting through `scala.util.Sorting`, but the constraints remain the same.

Comment: I hereby raise my voice and ask for in-place Seq manipulation. And also proper file UI.</offtopic>

Comment: The discussion soc mentions is here: http://scala-programming-language.1934581.n4.nabble.com/In-place-mutable-operations-td3162695.html