# Can you sort a mutable Scala collection in place?

Tags: scala, sorting, collections

Is it possible to sort an ArrayBuffer, or other mutable Scala collection, in place? I see that ArrayBuffer.sorted (and sortBy) returns a new collection, and Sorting.quicksort does sort an Array in place but doesn't work on ArrayBuffers.

The reason I ask is that I'm using combineByKey in Spark to build collections of scored objects that are limited in size (like a "top ten" list by key). If I merge in a new object and the collection is already at capacity, I need to drop the lowest-scored object. I could use a sorted collection like a PriorityQueue or SortedSet, but I don't need to keep the collections sorted all the time, only in the case when a collection fills up.

So is there some way to sort an ArrayBuffer or ListBuffer in place? Or is there some other collection that supports appending and sorting in place? I'm sure there's a better way to do this, but I'm new to Scala.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4686184/scala-sort-indexedseq-in-place , but not really an answer (there was a newer question in '14 closed for that one .. not sure if '15 brings relevant changes)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are presently no facilities for sorting collections in place.  That said, if you expect to have to do sorting extremely rarely, you could investigate supporting both separately e.g. as `Either[PriorityQueue[A], ArrayBuffer[A]]`; or if you expect sorting to be fairly common you should use a data structure where you don't pay such a penalty each time you add an element--meaning just use the `SortedSet` or `PriorityQueue`.  Otherwise you'll get slow *really* fast.  (`n^2 log n` gets big quickly, which is what you get if you do a full sort each time you add a new element.)

Comment: Thanks for this. I think I'll use a reversed PriorityQueue, so the lowest-scored objects come out first on dequeue. That way if the number of objects per key goes far beyond the "top ten" that I'm keeping, I won't run afoul of that pitfall you mentioned.

Answer (score 6):

You can use Java's sorting utilities.

Here is an example:

```
val myArray = Array(1,12,5,6)
java.util.Arrays.sort(myArray)
```

At the REPL:

```
> myArray
res3: Array[Int] = Array(1, 5, 6, 12)
```

If what you have is a Scala `ArrayBuffer` then call `toArray` to convert it to an Array.

Of course, the `toArray` on `ArrayBuffer` induces the cost of coping the entire Buffer again. If this is costly, check if you can get your initial results in an `Array` instead of an `ArrayBuffer`. If the results are of fixed length and unlikely to grow, then you don't rally need the dynamic expansion features of `ArrayBuffer`.

Comment: If you want to convert your ArrayBuffer to an Array, then you could use Sorting.quicksort(myArray) to sort it in place without resorting to the Java library. But in my case I didn't want to convert my buffer to a fixed-size array, because I had more elements to add to it.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Scala's `JavaConverters` to delegate to Java's `Arrays.sort` with 1 line of code.

Assume you have instances of `Foo` in a mutable buffer that you want to sort in place with the comparator `fooComparator`.

```
import scala.collection.mutable
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

…

val buffer = mutable.ArrayBuffer[Foo]()

…

buffer.asJava.sort(fooComparator) // sort "in place" (actually hides 1 copy)
```

However for extreme performance it seems that `ArrayBuffer` just can't be used and the plain fixed size `Array` is the way to go. The good thing is that `JavaConverters.asJava` does not copy the items. However Java's `List.sort` method internally copies the items to an `Array` and calls `Arrays.sort`. (It then assigns the sorted items back to original collection)

Perhaps the "full solution" would be to define your own version of Scala's `ArrayBuffer` that exposes the underlying array for sorting. Implementing your own collection types that can do all the same things as the original, plus your own tricks in Scala is usually easy due to the way how Scala's collection library is set up.